# Foco duplicado ao usar requestFocus em um EditText

Tags: android

Criei uma tela com 2 campos `EditText`, um com entrada numérica e outro texto. O que pretendo é executar uma validação no primeiro campo quando este perder o foco, e se der inválido, retornar o foco para esse primeiro campo para ser redigitado.

O problema está quando uso `.requestfocus()`, os dois campos ficam com o cursor de foco, mesmo usando `.clearfocus()` no segundo campo, o cursor fica só no primeiro mas se digito algo ele assume o teclado e a entrada dos dados no segundo campo.

Pra mim deveria ser óbvio quando requisitar o foco de um campo, este ser selecionado assumindo suas configurações e automaticamente desativar o outro.
Coloco abaixo um exemplo bem simples.
Agradeço a quem possa me esclarecer.

```
package com.example.android.teste;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText numero, texto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    numero = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    texto = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    numero.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
            //Executo uma validação e conforme resultado inválido retorno no campo para redigitar.
            numero.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Troque por algo assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText numero, texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        numero = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        texto = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        texto.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!numeroPassouNaValidacao() && hasFocus) {
                view.clearFocus();
                esconderTeclado(view);
                numero.requestFocus();
                mostrarTeclado(numero);
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean numeroPassouNaValidacao() {
        return false;
    }


    private void esconderTeclado(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    private void mostrarTeclado(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
    }



}
```

O que resolveu foi uma combinação de passar o listener para o outro EditText (o que pode dar trabalho se forem vários campos, mas foi o único jeito que resolveu), aplicar `clearFocus()` na View que acabou de receber o foco, esconder o teclado manualmente (senão ele fica na tela), fazer o `requestFocus()` no campo do número e mandar mostrar o teclado.